# How to change the default IconButton in Ract MUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am facing a strange problem, I am trying to make a `textfield` that has an icon on the side. I use `IconButton` to set the icon. But there is a problem, my `IconButton` has an eye icon by default, and I cannot change it, I want to use a different icon. I did not find any information on this on the net, the documentation says that there is no icon by default. But I have it!

my textfield:

```
import React from 'react';

import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Input from '@mui/material/Input';
import InputAdornment from '@mui/material/InputAdornment';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Visibility from '@mui/icons-material/Visibility';
import ReplayIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Replay';

const EditUserTextField = () => (
  <FormControl>
    <Input
      endAdornment={
            (
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton>
                  <Visibility />
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            )
        }
    />
  </FormControl>
);

export default EditUserTextField;
```

Result: [image]

Also I was trying to change the icon as indicated in the documentation:

```
<InputAdornment position="end">
            <IconButton>
              <ReplayIcon />
              <Visibility />
            </IconButton>
          </InputAdornment>
```

Result:
[image]

Why?

Comment: You just need to remove the `Visibility` component inside the `IconButton`. Typically `IconButton` doesn't have a default icon, but you included the icon `Visibility`(eye) by yourself.

Comment: @hotcakedev Oh, that was a stupid question. For some reason, I thought that `Visibility` makes the icon visible